# Overwrite a PDF item type with ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-online, pdf, arcgis-python-api

I'm trying to overwrite an existing PDF ArcGIS Online item using ArcGIS API for Python.

```
props = {
    "type":"PDF",
    "title":file_name,
    "overwrite":True
    }

data = os.path.join(tempFolder, "{}.pdf".format(file_name))

gis.content.add(item_properties=props, data=data)
```

Returns

```
RuntimeError: Item already exists
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
props = {
    "type":"PDF",
    "title":file_name,
    "overwrite":True
    }

data = os.path.join(tempFolder, "{}.pdf".format(file_name))

item = gis.content.get('itemuniqueid')
item.update(item_properties=props, data=data)
```

More info can be found in the arcgis api reference [reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.update).